# Ubuntu Zend Optimizer on Php 5.3.x

Tags: linux, ubuntu

currently I have some php codes I want to run on my ubuntu 12.4.5 x64 server, the link is http://104.131.254.163/

But it shows the error that Zend Optimizer is not installed.

I have browse through the internet trying to find a solution to install Zend Optimizer. But at the end I found out that php 5.3.x does not support Zend Optimizer, someone suggest that for php 5.3.x we should just install zend guard loader instead.

Therefore I'm getting confuse.
Should I downgrade php to 5.2.x or install zend guard loader? And does 5.3.x really not suppor Zend Optimizer?

I just wanna solve the problem and make my code runable, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Optimizer is a predecessor to Zend Loader. Both of them are runtime decoders that handle files that were encoded by Zend Guard. Simply put - if you're using php 5.2 or lower, you need the Optimizer decoder, else you need the Loader. Don't get confused, it's not really that complicated, just [follow the instructions](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Guard/zend-guard.htm#install.htm) and google around.

Also, for security reasons, it's better you don't share that IP you linked there on the internet (share a print screen of the page if you must).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into your answer